Is there any difference in performance between filters at the air return register and filters near the air handler?
I am doing some kitchen remodeling that will require running a different air return. It will give me the opportunity to put a filter/grill assembly in the kitchen, so that the filter can be more easily and conveniently changed from inside the house, rather than at the air handler in the crawl space. Does it matter? Is there any difference in performance between filters at the air return register, and filters in a rack by the air handler?

The only difference I can think of is number of filters.  Many HVAC systems have multiple returns (depends on size)—if you have to replace two+ filters instead of one.  Just a matter of cost tradeoff between the convenience of not having to get into your crawlspace.
In my house, the HVAC blowers (two zones) are in the basement and attic (with hatch stairs), so replacing the filters at the unit is no biggie.  Replacing the filter at the return would actually be a bigger hassle because I'd need to get a ladder out to reach them.

Yeah, this is just a 1-ton system, with one filter. And I'm just thinking it will be easier, more comfortable and convenient to change the filter in the kitchen than in the crawlspace, that's all. Just wondering if that will change the performance of the system at all, I can't see how it would.

No, it should not affect performance.
